# Remove default "Converted" button from Lead path in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, leads, lead-conversion

Is there a way to remove the default "Converted" button from Lead path in Lightning Experience or to block with a message?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create a validation rule or trigger to prevent conversion, or you can create a new profile, remove the Convert Lead permission, and assign this profile to your users. You can't directly remove the Converted status from the path, as you must always have at least one converted picklist value in the Lead Status field, and must have at least one converted picklist value per Record Type.

Comment: I don't want to prevent conversion, lead is being converted from trigger with some more changes in record when we set the Status as "Visit Done", but "Converted" opens a modal to set the values manually which can cause inconsistent data.

Comment: @AdityaVijay I think you can override the pop-up by overriding the convert button, but you can't remove the status from the list without setting restrictive permissions.